# arduino enter input from computer to LCD

Tags: input, arduino, lcd

I want to take input as a char and concatenate them and write LCD. However I can't it. Also, ı want to not show a symbol which is about enter on LCD. 
In this code, input does not written by serial monitor.

```cpp
#include < LiquidCrystal.h >

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
char karakter;
int ksayi;
String yazi = "";
String kaydirilacak = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.home();
  lcd.print("Hello World");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();
}
void loop() {
  ksayi = Serial.available();
  if (ksayi > 0) {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      karakter = Serial.read();
      if (karakter != '/n') {
        yazi += karakter;
      } 
      else {
        kaydirilacak = yazi;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.write(Serial.read(); yazi = "";
      }
    }
  }
  Kaydirmaca(kaydirilacak);
}

void Kaydirmaca(String s) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
    delay(275);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out Serial.read(), which returns nothing because serial.available() is zero.

Also, your code does not compile. You are missing an end parenthesis.

```cpp
else {
  kaydirilacak=yazi;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.write(Serial.read();
  yazi="";
}
```